# What directory does homebrew use to build programs?

Tags: homebrew

I would like to change the directory that homebrew uses when it builds programs

Is that possible? I didn't find such option in brew command

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you install a Homebrew package, if it needs to compile it from source, it will extract the files to `/tmp/package-XXXXXX` and compile them there before installing to `/usr/local/Cellar/package`.

You can specify a different temp folder by setting an environment variable...

```
export HOMEBREW_TEMP=/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/temp
```

Answer (score 2):

The manpage of Homebrew version 0.9.9 suggest something different:

the default folder Hombrew uses to do its things (including compiling) is `~/Library/Caches/Homebrew`, and you can change it by setting `HOMEBREW_CACHE` environmental variable. The environmental variable can be set by editing the hidden file `.bash_profile` in the user folder, e.g.:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

then add

```
export HOMEBREW_CACHE=/path/to/folder
```

Remember to do a `source ~/.bash_profile` to load the new environmental variable in already opened terminal sessions.

Brew manpage about `HOMEBREW_TEMP`:

```
HOMEBREW_TEMP

    If set, instructs Homebrew to use HOMEBREW_TEMP as the temporary directory
    for building  packages.
    This  may be needed if your system temp directory and Homebrew Prefix are
    on different volumes, as OS X has trouble moving symlinks across volumes
    when the target does not yet exist.

    This issue typically occurs when using FileVault or custom SSD configurations.
```

Unless this fits your settings, you should avoid setting `HOMEBREW_TEMP`.